# Google Map Api v3 Clusterer - which markers are groupped?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cluster-analysis, google-maps-markers

if i use clustering on my google maps api, how can i get info about which markers are grouped in cluster? is it possible to get?

it's with google map api v3.

thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the marker clusterer http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/ then you can listen to the 'clusterclick' event listener to the MarkerCluster.

The callback will be passed the cluster that was clicked on and you can call:
getCenter, getSize and getMarkers

With that information you should be able to do what you need to

Comment: +1 Excellent resource! never knew about this repository, thanks